# Creating A Tableau Calculated field based of a date in two fields

Tags: date, filter, tableau-api, calculated-field

In Tableau I've got a few reports that I like to cross reference with our live database, but as it is live, I have to filter out which accounts were active at the time of the ran report, based on effective and termination dates. Is there any way to combine the bottom two filters into one using a calculated field? One thing to note is every account on file has an effective date, and only terminated accounts have terminated dates, leaving currently active accounts as of today with a null value. If I could even incorporate the Report Date Checkbox into the field too, that'd be sweet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The brief answer is that you cannot do that. The reasons are three:

- Tableau does not support parameters that take more than one values
- Tableau does not support dynamic parameters
- You still need a parameter to filter your query

Even if you pass both effective and termination dates to a calculated field, you will still need parameters to filter your query and these parameters can only take one value each and cannot be dynamic (ie. they cannot change values depending on the calculated field's value).